# Upload a binary file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

I am writing a REST API using rails and grape, in which I need to upload files.

```
post :create_file do
    path = Rails.root.join 'public','uploads',params[:name]
    File.open(path,'wb'){|f| f.write(request.body.read) }
    {
        message:'success'
    }
  end
```

When uploading a text file it works fine;
But something goes wrong when uploading a binary file, like files broken.

headers:`HTTP/1.1
*/*
no-cache
localhost:3000
Keep-Alive
Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)
gzip,deflate
nil`

params:

```
name:"test.png"
'test.png':Hashie::Mash (5 elements)
'rout_info':'version=, method=POST, path=/api/users/create_file(.:format)
```

---

I changed code to:

```
post :create_file do
    path = Rails.root.join 'public','uploads',params[:name]
    file = params['bg.png']
    file2 = request.body
    File.open(path,'wb'){|f| f.write(file2.read) }
    {
        message:file.read
    }
  end
```

debug message :
file:

```
filename="bg.png"
type="application/octet-stream"
name="bg.png"
tempfile=#<File:0x007fd7694b9bd0>
head="Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bg.png"; filename="bg.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"
```

file2:

```
#<File:0x007fd7694c8270>
```

if I use `file.read`, i got a empty file, and if I use `file2.read`, i got the file broken.

==========================================

At last it was solved by `file.tempfile.read`
thanks @maxd anyway

Comment: Add `headers` to log or just print them use `p` and provide output.

Answer (score -1):

Your client should specify correct `Content-Type` header and upload binary data in correspond format:

Specify `application/octet-stream` if you want to upload binary data as request body (seems like you code accept data in this format):

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

or specify `multipart/form-data` and upload binary data in [multipart format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) (details is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)):

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data
```

Comment: it is  multipart/form-data now

Comment: so I should not get files in request.body?